# How can i setup react-native-web with nx?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, nginx

I need to set up **react-native-web** with **nx**, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, you need to create your nx workspace like the following:

`npx create-nx-workspace acme --preset=empty`

then you just create the new app you have with

`nx g @nrwl/react:app website --style=none`

then you can add the `react-native-web` package:

`yarn add react-native-web`

there may be some babel errors in serving the app, but most of them could be fixed using the following package.

`yarn add -D babel-plugin-react-native-web`

now depending on if you're still debugging your code you can use the `nx serve` command.

`nx serve website`

or if you want to serve the app online you can just export the app and put the static files behind an Nginx Server.

you can always use `nx` [blog article](https://blog.nrwl.io/introducing-react-native-support-for-nx-48d335e90c89) on how to share `react` and `react-native` libraries on your workspace.

Comment: i got this error
> nx run stores-app:serve:development
Cannot read property 'projects' of undefined
 >  NX   Running target "stores-app:serve" failed

   Failed tasks:

   - stores-app:serve:development

   Hint: run the command with --verbose for more details.

Comment: this may be some kind of error that serving your app maybe.
maybe having a verbose logging could help